# Is there a way to know when a pop up from a drop down list is displayed anywhere in an application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'd like to know if there is a way to tell when a pop up is shown at any time. When I say pop up I mean pop up like a dropdownlist is opened.

Comment: For a spark dropdownlist you can check for the property dropdownList.isDropDownOpen. If you want track when it is opened then you can use the open event for it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to track pop ups that occur from any dropdown list. I was thinking maybe they were using the pop up manager so I could track it better. I need to find the size and position of any pop up that occurs.